# Android as host not working, Unity LLAPI

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

so i'll try my best to post this properly. I asked this before on unity forums, but i didn't found an answer yet, here is the [link](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/llapi-problems-on-android.430899/) if you want it.

I have a working demo of a Server side broadcasting and Client reciving the message parsing and using the info to connect to the server.

```
 NetworkTransport.Init();
 NetworkTransport.AddHost(defaultTopology, PORT)
 NetworkTransport.StartBroadcastDiscovery(id,broadcastport,..,..)
 NetworkTransport.Receive(..,..)
 NetworkTransport.Connect(..,..)
```

etc. I can go on further detail on code if you want it, but as far as its working on PC fine I think the code is fine.

When I try the same with **PC as server, Android as Client**, if the Android device act as a client, he don't recieve the broadcast from the server but i can connect manually(i know the IP of my local machine) and i can send and recieve messages.(This is okay except for the broadcast problem that would be nice to fix)

If the **Android act as Server and PC client**, the PC recieves the broadcast but can't connect to the Android neither automatically nor manually.

I tested with 2 Androids an the results are bad too.
The client didn't recieve the broadcast and if I try the manual connection the server didn't recieve the connect event. The main goal is using 2 androids.

I searched for problems with the Network and Unity but i only found some people talking about the Android Manifest but not saying exactly what to do about. If you can point me to the correct direction with this i would apreciate.

Also maybe the Android 6 permissions have something to do with that?

I personally think that the android cant recieve nothing until is conected, so when he acts as Client he don't recieve the broadcast but can connect and then works fine, but as a Server he cant recieve the connection.

Maybe has something to do on Android Ports? I usually use 25001.

Using Unity 5.3.5f1

Thanks and sorry for my poor english.

**Edit:** 
I changed to Unity 5.4 to check about Android 6 permisions and isn't working too.
You have a demo [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ig3z9z9iljt0wl4/NetTest.rar?dl=0) if you want to try
Is an isolation from another project so maybe you find comented delegates and other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is indeed the Android Manifest. I see no other reason why this is not working. The method permission query is handled changed on Android 6.0. You have to download Unity 5.4 to fix this problem.

Comment: The Android Manifest was my first think, i will try and let you know, anyway I only use the Internet permission(as far as i know) and is not dangerous at all to need to be asked on runtime.

Comment: I believe that permission stuff is now done from code in Android 6 not from the Manifest.

Comment: oh, I though that was just the dangerous permisions, downloading 5.4.. :)

Comment: That's fine. Let me know if that works after downloading 5.4. It should. Otherwise, I will file bug report with Unity.

Comment: Definetly not working, i tried to isolate the net part as much as I can and made a NetworkDemo. If you have time to test if work on you will be nice.

Maybe the problem is just on my configuration, my router my ports.... etc and is not an Unity bug.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ig3z9z9iljt0wl4/NetTest.rar?dl=0

Comment: Ok. Can you isolate just the network stuff and upload the project somewhere and provide the link here. I will run this on my Android devices to see what's going on. I also want to know the model number of your Android device.

Comment: i was posting the link on the comment but pressed enter by mistake ):

Comment: Ok. That will take time to test as  I have to set things up. Will get back to you within 5 hours

Comment: did you figure out something?

Comment: I only had access to one Android devices and was waiting to get another Android device. I just want to make sure to test this on 2 Android devices. I will get one today from work and reply to you.

Comment: Ok, on my side isn't working "well" with PC + Android too.

Comment: I did experiment for couple of days and it worked with Android 4.xx. It didn't work with 6. I think you should file for a bug. This is seems like a permission problem to me. File for a bug with Unity.

Comment: Thanks for your time on that question, I've never reported a bug on unity so if u can do it will be nice or point me on how to do it. I hope they patch it soon.